# How to get homography matrix from gps information

Tags: python, opencv, gps, robotics, drone.io

I am working a gps-denied UAV localization project. I am reading this paper **GPS-Denied UAV Localization using Pre-existing Satellite Imagery**. In this paper, they try to align a UAV frame sequentially with a satellite map using an homography. The first homography is estimated using the GPS information stored in the first UAV frame. In the code, I don't see any information about this part. I am wondering if someone can explain this or point me to some reference that can help.

Comment: do you know gps-to-pixel correspondences for current frame pixels and for satellite images?

Comment: @Micka, Yes. based on the paper `We extract the GPS-aligned satellite map from Google Earth Pro. The UAV imagery was captured in April, 2013, and the satellite imagery in May, 2012. High-accuracy RTK GPS (latitude, longitude, and altitude) is included in the metadata of each UAV frame in the dataset`

Comment: if you have the gps for each pixel, just use 4+ pixel-pairs with identical gps coordinates in your homography computation.